# How to merge two columns in pandas dataframe into a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two dataframes into a new dataframe, where two columns will be merged as a list. For example: here is df1

```
   tkt_ticket_opened  tkt_adjtimetorepair  result_data_cohort_id
0      2017-01-09 05             0.075883                      1
1      2017-01-09 06             0.286550                      1
2      2017-01-09 07             0.124234                      1
3      2017-01-09 08             0.144504                      1
4      2017-01-09 09             0.416698                      1
5      2017-01-09 10             0.103199                      1
6      2017-01-09 11             0.063608                      1
7      2017-01-09 12             0.378695                      1
8      2017-01-09 13             0.686515                      1
9      2017-01-09 14             0.671016                      1
10     2017-01-09 15             0.406588                      1
11     2017-01-09 16             0.957627                      1
12     2017-01-09 17             0.504509                      1
13     2017-01-09 18             0.416487                      1
14     2017-01-09 19             0.412306                      1
15     2017-01-09 20             0.929061                      1
16     2017-01-09 21             0.421006                      1
17     2017-01-09 22             0.365754                      1
18     2017-01-09 23             0.557050                      1
```

df2

```
   tkt_ticket_opened  tkt_adjtimetorepair  result_data_cohort_id
0      2017-01-09 05             0.065538                      0
1      2017-01-09 06             0.379438                      0
2      2017-01-09 07             0.190816                      0
3      2017-01-09 08             0.594454                      0
4      2017-01-09 09             0.649041                      0
5      2017-01-09 10             0.509891                      0
6      2017-01-09 11             0.260283                      0
7      2017-01-09 12             0.340179                      0
8      2017-01-09 13             0.402101                      0
9      2017-01-09 14             0.497638                      0
10     2017-01-09 15             0.373385                      0
11     2017-01-09 16             0.533326                      0
12     2017-01-09 17             0.366825                      0
13     2017-01-09 18             0.892164                      0
14     2017-01-09 19             0.723326                      0
15     2017-01-09 20             1.088171                      0
16     2017-01-09 21             0.408264                      0
17     2017-01-09 22             0.507147                      0
18     2017-01-09 23             0.486486                      0
```

the resulting dataframe would be

```
   tkt_ticket_opened  tkt_adjtimetorepair  
0      2017-01-09 05             [0.075883, 0.065538 ]                 
1      2017-01-09 06             [0.286550, 0.379438 ]                 
2      2017-01-09 07             [0.124234, 0.190816 ]                   
....
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, merge the data set:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on= 'tkt_ticket_opened')
```

Next, we'll grab arrays containing values of both `tkt_adjtimetorepair` columns and convert them to lists:

```
merged['tkt_adjtimetorepair'] = merged[['tkt_adjtimetorepair_x', 'tkt_adjtimetorepair_y']].values.tolist()

# cleanup
merged.drop(['tkt_adjtimetorepair_x', 'tkt_adjtimetorepair_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

We can assign this output directly to a column.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]], columns=["tkt_ticket_opened", "tkt_adjtimetorepair"])
df_b = pd.DataFrame([[1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]], columns=["tkt_ticket_opened", "tkt_adjtimetorepair"])
```

One way to combine the data is by constructing series based on the your desired result. With the simplified version of your DataFrames, you can zip the columns together to produce the desired result:

```
df_c = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict(tkt_ticket_opened=df_a["tkt_ticket_opened"], 
                tkt_adjtimetorepair=pd.Series(zip(df_a["tkt_adjtimetorepair"], 
                                                  df_b["tkt_adjtimetorepair"])).map(list)))

df_c.head()


     tkt_ticket_opened   tkt_adjtimetorepair

0         1                  [3, 4]

1         2                  [3, 4]

2         3                  [3, 4]
```

**Option 2:**

The same result can also be achieved by merging the DataFrames on the key you want, and then sending the two columns to a list:

```
df_c = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on="tkt_ticket_opened")
df_c["tkt_adjtimetorepair"] = df_c[["tkt_adjtimetorepair_x", "tkt_adjtimetorepair_y"]].values.tolist()
df_c = df_c[["tkt_ticket_opened", "tkt_adjtimetorepair"]]

df_c.head()

     tkt_ticket_opened   tkt_adjtimetorepair

0         1                  [3, 4]

1         2                  [3, 4]

2         3                  [3, 4]
```

I prefer **Option 2** because is more efficient and a better pandas solution.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer RMatt. I appreciate you explaining the nuances of the two options :). Unfortunately, I will have to keep Andrew's answer as the accepted response since he was first.